# Cannot write to Firestore from client app when using Firestore Emulator

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I'm having problems creating documents in Firestore while using Firestore Emulator. Below is the error I see in logs:

> W/Firestore(13200): (24.0.1) [WriteStream]: (aa74142) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNKNOWN, description=null, cause=null}.

In my app, after user signs up, I check if there is a document related to this user. This read operation succeeds, therefore I conclude that I can read from Firestore. If there isn't a document related to the user, a document gets created. This is the point that the code gets stuck. The write operation does not return. It does not throw an exception either.

I'm using both Authentication and Firestore emulators.

This problem does not occur all the time. For example in the app, when a new FCM token has been generated, the token is saved into the Firestore and this works without any issues. I can see the document in Firestore Emulator Dashboard. I can also create documents manually using the dashboard.

The problem occurs both on physical device and Android Emulator. While testing on physical device, I connect to the Firestore Emulator by specifying the IP address of my computer which the Firestore Emulator is running on. On Android Emulator, I provide `localhost` as the host of the Firestore Emulator.

I've also created an [issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/8178) in flutterfire repository.

Output of `flutter doctor`:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.1, on Pop!_OS 21.10 5.15.23-76051523-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0-rc1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.64.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Versions of `cloud_firestore` and `firebase_core` packages:

```
cloud_firestore: ^3.1.8
firebase_core: ^1.12.0
```

Comment: Could you share any code related to the Firestore emulator, FCM, and others that can clarify what you are trying to do? On which platform are you running the Firebase Emulator (Windows, Linux, Mac OS)?

Answer (score 0):

My problem with the emulator suite was the Kaspersky antivirus. After disabling it, everything works fine. Maybe this help you!

Comment: I don't have any antivirus installed on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me as well and never has before.  The bug I experience is when I create a document using the Android emulator it's like I can't write to it from any other source.  So for example when testing I'll be using separate accounts in my app in the Android emulator, Firefox, and on web for my Android phone.  If the doc I'm trying to write to was created by the emulator, I can't write to it from either web on my phone or my computer's browser.  If I use the Chrome emulator instead everything works fine.  It also works fine if I create the doc initially on my phone or browser then write to it from the android emulator/web/web for android phone.  Obviously it's really hard to debug since it only happens while creating the initial doc from the Android emulator.

Edit: After hooking up the debugger to Chrome and then creating the raid doc in the Android emulator I was able to fix my problem.  I believe there is a recent change to the way the Android emulator handles timestamps that is creating my error.

This is what a timestamp stored in Firebase by the Android emulator looks like using Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now());: Timestamp(seconds=1646095038, nanoseconds=780498000)

In Chrome the same command looks like this:
Timestamp(seconds=1646095976, nanoseconds=800000000) Chrome

What is happening in the last week is this chunk of code designed to get the most recent raid doc in my MMORPG app is failing to get a result from firebase on web when the timestamp is created in the Android emulator:

```
   //update most recent raid doc
  Future<void> updateRaid(String guildName, Raid raid) async {
    var snap = await _db
        .collection('guilds')
        .doc(guildName)
        .collection('raids')
        .where('raidDocCreated', isEqualTo: raid.raidDocCreated)
        .get();
    var docId = snap.docs[0].id;
    return _db
        .collection('guilds')
        .doc(guildName)
        .collection('raids')
        .doc(docId)
        .set(raid.toJson());
  }
```

Bottom line is if you are doing something similar to this where you are trying to query a timestamp in firebase stored by the Android emulator, web will not compare equality accurately.  I was able to fix this problem by storing an int in the database to query the most recently created doc by instead of a Timestamp using DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.  Now when my doc gets created on the Android emulator, web can properly compare the equality of the raidDocCreatedAt variable.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was having has been resolved. I don't know which change was behind this but I remember making several upgrades in the environment that I run the Firebase Emulators. It might as well be changing the version of node or upgrading Firebase Admin SDK.